# How to get an immutable entity from its aggregate in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregate, entities

An aggregate (`Article`) has an entity (`SmsContent`) with a property (`enabled`) that only can change if a condition on the aggregate is met.

e.g.

```php
<?php
//Aggregate
class Article {

    /** @var User */
    protected $user;

    /** @var SmsOutput */
    protected sms;

    ...

    public function enableSms() {
        if($this->user->hasPermission('sms')) {
            throw new PermissionDeniedException('sms');
        }
        $this->sms->enable();
        retutn $this;
    }

    public function getSms() {
        return $this->sms;
    }

    ...
}

//Entity
class SmsOutput {

    /** @var boolean */
    protected enabled = false;

    ...

    public function enable() {
        $this->enable = true;
    }

    ...
}
```

How should you get the `SmsContent` entity from the `Article` without being able to change the enabled property from outside the aggregate?

For example:

```
$article->getSms()->enable();
```

How is this handled in DDD?

Comment: I suppose you don't use CQRS (splitting the Write from the Read), that's why you need to query the Aggregate? I'm asking just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options, depending on the architecture.

**1. Use CQRS**

In CQRS the Write is separated from the Read. This means that you don't interrogate the Aggregate, ever. You don't have any getters, only command handlers. If you can't interrogate the Aggregate you can't access any nested entity either. If you need to get data you do it only from a projection/read model that are read-only by default.

**2. Use a different interface for returned entities**

In this case you return the entity but it is type-hinted as being a sub-set of the actual entity. In your case you could have something like this:

```
<?php

interface SmsOutput
{
    //...
    public function isEnabled(): bool;
    //...
}


//Entity
class SmsOutputWritable implements SmsOutput
{

    /** @var boolean */
    private $enabled = false;

    //...

    public function enable()
    {
        $this->enabled = true;
    }

    public function isEnabled(): bool
    {
        return $this->enabled;
    }

    //...
}

//Aggregate
class Article
{

    /** @var User */
    private $user;

    /** @var SmsOutputWritable */
    private $sms;

    //...

    public function enableSms(): void //no return values, see CQS
    {
        if ($this->user->hasPermission('sms')) {
            throw new PermissionDeniedException('sms');
        }

        $this->sms->enable();
    }

    public function getSms(): SmsOutput
    {
        return $this->sms;
    }

    //...
}
```

Although the caller gets a `SmsOutputWritable` it does not know about this.

*P.S. Anyway, even if the caller knows (or casts) that the returned value is `SmsOutputWritable` and call `SmsOutputWritable::enable()` nothing really happens because the caller can't persist the changes to the `repository`, only entire aggregates can be persisted not individual nested entities. This is because aggregates and/or nested entities don't persist themselves, only an `Application service` can do this, using a `repository`.*

Comment: No, I am not using CQRS at this point. 
But if the caller persists the aggregate through its repository, the enabled property will be persitsed as "true", because the getSms() function returns a reference to the SmsOutputWritable object.

Comment: Yes, but the type-hinting should hide that possibility. Or you can return a clone.

Answer (score 0):

> How should you get the SmsContent entity from the Article without being able to change the enabled property from outside the aggregate?

Short answer: You don't.  You get an immutable representation (ie: a value type) of the `SmsContent.State` from the Aggregate Root.

That's the approach taken by Evans in *Domain Driven Design*.  There have been a couple of innovations that have gained traction since then.

One is the idea that a single entity can serve in multiple *roles*.  Rather than having a single repository that serves many different use cases, you might have many repositories that handle specific cases.  Here, that might look like a repository that returns the Aggregate Root when you want to be able to change something, and a different repository that returns a view/projection for use cases that only inspect the data.

This separation goes really well with ideas like *lazy loading*; if you aren't going to need some data for a particular use case, you interact with a repository that doesn't load it.

Udi Dahan's essay [Better Domain-Driven Design Implementation](http://udidahan.com/2007/03/06/better-domain-driven-design-implementation/) provides a high level overview.

> This looks a lot like the CQRS suggestion of Constantin. I mean, when you start using different repositories for reads and writes, then you're already with one feet in CQRS

It does, but there are a few intermediate steps along the way; [CQS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html), [responsibility driven design](http://www.wirfs-brock.com/PDFs/A_Brief-Tour-of-RDD.pdf).

Comment: Do you know any good code example repositories, that uses this approach? Or DDD in general.

Comment: This looks a lot like the CQRS suggestion of Constantin. I mean, when you start using different repositories for reads and writes, then you're already with one feet in CQRS.